# Can a Lambda in a VPC be triggered by an S3 object creation event or API Gateway without routing through NAT Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, amazon-neptune

If my design involves a Neptune cluster in a VPC in a private subnet and a lambda running in the same VPC subnet, can this be triggered using API Gateway/S3 events without using the NAT Gateway?

The idea is to have 2 separate lambdas - one for bulk loading data into Neptune using S3 event triggers, the other lambda triggered by API Gateway to query Neptune. I also have a S3 VPC endpoint setup for loading data into Neptune.

Is there any use for a NAT Gateway in this design? Can the Lambda send responses back to the API Gateway without routing through NAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your Lambda function is in a VPC, this does not impact how the Lambda function is **invoked**.

Therefore, Amazon S3 can trigger your Lambda function when an object is created. Your Lambda function will then run in the VPC and communicate with Neptune.

You do *not* require a NAT Gateway since the Lambda function is being triggered *outside* your VPC.

Comment: Thanks. I was also trying to understand how the Lambda sends the response back to the API Gateway without using the NAT (Tried this via console - and it worked without invoking the NAT) Do you happen to know how that works?

Comment: The Lambda function uses `return` to pass the response back to the AWS Lambda service, which will forward it to API Gateway. It happens in the back-end, not in the VPC.